# Change CSS class to "active" for navigation links in Meteor

Tags: javascript, css, meteor

What is the best way to detect the current route in Meteor and apply a CSS class of "active" to the correct navigation elements?

Note: I am using Iron Router

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using Iron Router, it's definitely [Iron Router Active](https://github.com/zimme/meteor-iron-router-active).  I feel a bit guilty just providing a link to a package as the answer, but it is the best answer.